# command to report in sonar 5.2

Tags: sonar-runner, sonarqube5.2

I installed plugin "sonar-report-plugin" to get PDF report from sonar.
I have done all required setup in sonar for this plugin.

Now I just want to know what command to execute to get the report as "sonar-runner report" command is no longer functional in sonarqube5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed for technical reasons the Report plugin could not be kept compatible with SonarQube 5.2. Support is back in version 5.3, which first release candidate has been published today.
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+5.2+Upgrade+Notes

Comment: thanks for the help.
I am switching to earlier version of sonarqube to get the PDF.